# twitter bootstrap vertical tab left border height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want the vertical border of the vertical tab to run on the whole page instead of finishing off where the tabs end.

[image: expecting an output like this] however since I have given border-right on the tab it ends

with the last tab that is trending. Giving border-right to the content makes sure the height of the border is right but it spoils the spacing between tab and content.

HTML :-

```
<div class='tabbable tabs-left'>
          <ul class='nav nav-tabs'>
            <li class='active'>
              <a href="/startups?startup=All">All</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/startups?startup=New">New</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/startups?startup=Featured">Featured</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/startups?startup=Ending+Soon">Ending Soon</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/startups?startup=Trending">Trending</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you post you code too? Or a Bootply or fiddle?

Comment: where is your source cod which one you have a try this

Comment: the styling is coming from twitter bootstrap and I have not used any custom styling, image is the result which I have to get in html and css

Comment: @DevR Did my answer work for you? Or is it not what you needed?

Comment: @edsioufi will check it out after weekend and let you know

Answer (score 1):

This is not default Bootstrap behavior so you will have to modify the `css` a little. For this to work, the vertical tab `<ul>` and all of its parents should have the property `height: 100%`.

For `html` and `body` I would apply the styling directly but for the `<div>` and `<ul>` I would use custom class so as not to modify the Bootstrap classes to maintain expected behavior for eventual future use in other layouts.

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/axrwF/2/).

The `css` to add:

```
html{
    height: 100%;
}

body{
    height: 100%;
}

.tabbable.tabs-left.full-height{
    height: 100%;
}

.nav.nav-tabs.full-height{
    height: 100%;
}
```

The `html` to modify:

```
<body>
    <div class='tabbable tabs-left full-height'>
        <ul class='nav nav-tabs full-height'>
        ...........
```